# Why is my many-to-many relationship not being retrieved by NSFetchedResultsController?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, many-to-many, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a tableview where I am creating a sectioned list of bunches (sections) and buddies (rows).  The relationship between buddies and bunches is a many-to-many in core data.  I want to use NSFetchedResultsController to provide the data for this tableview.
Note: I used [this tutorial](https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2015/03/05/displaying-data-with-nsfetchedresultscontroller-and-swift/) to setup the NSFetchedResultsController

Here is my NSFetchedResultsController:

```
lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController = {
    let bunchesFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: Constants.CoreData.bunch)
    // "name" refers to the bunch name
    let primarySortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true, selector: "caseInsensitiveCompare:")
    bunchesFetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [primarySortDescriptor]

    let frc = NSFetchedResultsController(
        fetchRequest: bunchesFetchRequest,
        managedObjectContext: CoreDataStackManager.sharedInstance().managedObjectContext!,
        sectionNameKeyPath: "name",
        cacheName: nil
    )
    frc.delegate = self
    return frc
}()
```

When I go to get the number of buddies in a bunch, I always get a set with no buddies in it.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if let sections = fetchedResultsController.sections {
        let currentSection = sections[section] as! NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo
        let bunch = currentSection.objects[0] as! Bunch
        return bunch.buddies.count  // always returns 0
    }
    return 0
}
```

Is there something extra I have to do with the NSFetchedResultsController or another way I'm supposed to get the count?  If you could explain what's happening here with core data internals, that would be helpful too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use prefetching. With prefetching, you tell Core Data when you perform a fetch to also fetch the related objects you specify. So adding this line, when you fetch bunches you tell Core Data to prefetch the related buddies.

```
bunchesFetchRequest.relationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching = ["buddies"]
```